# ScrollMagic. Adding multiple classes to an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, scrollmagic

If I follow the scrollMagic instructions:

```
// add multiple classes to multiple elements defined by the selector '.classChange'
scene.setClassToggle(".classChange", "class1 class2 class3");
```

(http://scrollmagic.io/docs/ScrollMagic.Scene.html#setClassToggle)

I got this error in the console:

```
InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character
```

Because spaces between classes.

My entire scene code is:

```
              var ourScene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
                triggerElement: '.banner',
                triggerHook: 0,
                offset: 20
              })
              .setClassToggle('.banner', 'big small')
              .addTo(controller);
```

Removing space between "big small", it works, in other words, It works just with one class, not multiple classes.

How can I work with multiple classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While searching on web, I found that there is an open issue with scrollmagic which causes you a problem

> setClassToggle only supports single classes #313

To get around this you can use Greenstock .set tween method to add multiple classes.

Below is a codepen link that i found online addressing the above usage.

```
var setMultipleClasses = TweenMax.set($('p'), {
    className: "red bold"
});

// Create a ScrollMagic Scene
new ScrollMagic.Scene({
  triggerElement: "p"
})
.setTween(setMultipleClasses)
.addIndicators()
.addTo(ctrl);
```

http://codepen.io/ihatetomatoes/pen/9e18df235da9abb2766a61990094a368

Comment: How can I set the more than one TweenMax.set in above example?

Comment: I tried like this var setMultipleClasses = TweenMax.set($('.shipping_agency .animate_heading'), {className: "fadeIn"});
         .set($('.shipping_agency p'), {className: "fadeIn"});

var scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
        triggerElement:".shipping_agency"
    })
    .setTween(setMultipleClasses)
    .addTo(ctrl)
});

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: this is reported to be not working, so please don't even waste your time trying it.

<s>Did you try:</s>

```
...
.setClassToggle('.banner', 'big')
.setClassToggle('.banner', 'small')
...
```

Comment: Yes, I did it. It take effect only over last command (.small)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when I chain setClassToggle with different classes...

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the answer above is that TweenMax.set() will get rid of any other classes that were there.

Technically you can add more classes using

```
className: "+= red bold"
```

But then it does not seem to toggle these classes off.

The best method I have found is using a callback function.

```
// Create a ScrollMagic Scene
    new ScrollMagic.Scene({
      triggerElement: "p",
      triggerHook: 'onEnter'
    }).on('enter leave', function () {
        element.classList.toggle('toggle-on'); 
          element.classList.toggle('active');
      }).addTo(scrollMagicController)
```

See here what events you can use
https://scrollmagic.io/docs/ScrollMagic.Scene.html#on